# Remove vertical gap between two div when window is small

Tags: html, css

I am using float div structure for my website. In one scenario I have a problem of vertical space between two divs. I worked around but did not find solution for that. So can it be possible with minimal effort. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/70dht4gg/)

```
<div style="float:left; width:200px; background:#ff0000; height:300px; margin-right:10px">1</div>

<div style="float:left; width:200px; background:#ff0000; height:400px">2</div>

<div style="float:left; width:200px; background:#ff0000; height:300px;">3</div>
```

Comment: It's unclear what the issue is.

Comment: @amit, remove/reduce the css height:300px

Comment: @Arvind: height will be dynamic so cant play with the height

Comment: @Paulie_D: You can see vertical gap beetween first box and last box. That is the issue

Comment: What gap? There's only a gap between 1 & 2...in Chrome

Comment: Wait, do you mean when the window is too small? In that case you need to look into [**Masonry.js**](http://masonry.desandro.com/)

Comment: @paulie_D: Yes now you understand problem

Comment: See above...masonry.js

Answer (score 0):

Remove **margin-right:10px** css property for your div

Comment: think he means the gap between `1` and `3`, not `1` and `2`

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
html,body{margin:0px; padding:0px}
</style>
</head>
<div style="float:left; width:200px; background:#ff0000; height:300px;">1</div>
<div style="float:left; width:200px; background:#ff0000; height:400px">2</div>
<div style="float:left; width:200px; background:#ff0000; height:300px;">3</div>
```

Use this code.

Answer (score -1):

Simply do the following. Add `margin-top:-80px;`

**[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/70dht4gg/3/)**

```
 <div style="float:left; width:200px; background:#ff0000; height:300px;margin-top:-80px;">3</div>
```

Hope i have understood you right.

Comment: The boxes are dynamic and it can more than 3, So it is difficult to add margin in the div which has gap